# Android send parameters server .create request

Tags: java, android, http

i want to create request and i want to send to parameters to server,for example two strings(hello,hello)
i googled about this and i  wrote some code but i have debug error (my problem is a URL)
i want to send  2 strings in this url  http://*****/**/******.aspx?deviceId={id}&list={list}
deviceID={id) is a firs string for example divice id and  list={list} is second string  just hello

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://****/***/******.aspx?deviceId={id}&list={list}");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", android_id));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("list","Hello"));

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), android_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

}

Comment: A bit off-topic: [Google doesn't recommend using DefaultHttpClient](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). You can find alternatives on [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a GET method and you are trying to POST it, Am I correct?

if it is GET method you have to pass your request inside the URL itself, Like this

Your Previous code:

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
        "http://****/***/******.aspx?deviceId={id}&list={list}");
```

Now change to,

```
 HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(
        "http://****/***/******.aspx?deviceId="+android_id+"&list="+"Hello");
```

Comment: i do not know i little know about http

Comment: OK fine, who developed this web service now you are trying to access, ask them it has created in GET method or POST method? Because you used HttpPost, so the web service also should be in POST method then only you can access it. If it is in GET method you need to use HttpGet. got it

Comment: i asked him and this is a get  method

Comment: First you try that url in the web browser, pass the values manually

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't have to hard-code parameters in URL since you are using name value pair.
I think this should work without problems

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://****/***/******.aspx");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", android_id));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("list","Hello"));

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), android_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
}
```

Comment: this is  not working :(  i can not send two parameters to server

Comment: @user3233500 How did you test it?